# Release the "Q" ball

Tags: wordplay, visual, geometry, letters, physics

[image: release_the_Q_ball]

**Hit the "I" ball at such an angle that it creates a chain reaction which ultimately dislodges the "Q" ball.**

Whenever the ball in motion hits a stationary ball, the ball in motion replaces the stationary ball in the word, thus forming a new word.  The stationary ball is then set in motion at an angle of your choosing.

The balls always move in straight lines, never curves or arcs.

You may use the bumpers to deflect the trajectory of the ball in motion.  But don't worry too much about the [physics](https://www.britannica.com/science/light/Reflection-and-refraction) of it.

Words should be common and well-known, not obscure.

*For a more difficult version of this puzzle, see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118506).*

Comment: But where are the bumpers?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel — The bumpers (also called the bumper rails) are the dark green frame which surrounds the light green play area.  In other words, every side of the play area is a bumper rail.

Comment: Almost feel like this should've been done in reverse, such that you're hitting the Q ball, which is how billiards usually works...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think you mean cue ball, unless I'm missing a joke.

Comment: @Brandon_J No, that was it.  I know it's spelled "cue", but in this case, it's an actual letter Q, which is pronounced the same way, so it's a nice visual pun.

Comment: "bumpers" == "cushions", at least in my part of the world.

Comment: I think you should clarify that the replaced balls actually need to form words. You state that words should be common and well-known, however the actual problem statement is only: Dislodge the Q-Ball which you can do by just shooting straight down, finishing the game immediately.

Comment: Stunning puzzle!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky — Thanks!  See a more difficult version here:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118506/catching-the-l-train

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is one possible solution to this puzzle

> [image: The I replaces the E in SET to form SIT. Then the E replaces the A in QUOTA to form QUOTE. Then the A replaces the I in SIT to form SAT. Then the I replaces the O in QUITE to form QUITE. Then the O replaces the S in SAT to form OAT. Finally, the S replaces the Q in QUITE to form SUITE.]

Comment: Despite this being a very easy puzzle, this is an awesome answer. Well done.

Comment: OK, that's a fantastic puzzle (not just basic geometry/physics but word-letter replacement) and a beautiful answer (love me an animated puzzle solution). Upvotes all round.

Comment: @Randal'Thor — Thank you!  I was in the process of creating a complex Rube Goldberg arrangement with lots of balls, when this simple setup popped up, so I went with that.  Cap's animation really made it beautiful and fun.

Comment: Could I propose a gif that's a little easier to follow? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQctm.gif

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks, I'll edit it in.